# counting McGraw Hill

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there for eight men and five women
to stand in a line so that no two women stand next to each
other? [Hint: First position the men and then consider
possible positions for the women.]

Answer (score 1):

In such problems first position more items / persons , here men are more so allow them to sit first.

X M X M X M X M X M X M X M XMX

Now at X you can allow women to sit. Eight man can sit in 8! ways and there are 9 position to sit women, they can sit in $^9P_5$ ways.

Hope you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$8$ males in a line give $7$ inner plus $2$ outer positions where to place a female.

We can draw $5$ out of $9$ places for the females.

The males can be arranged in $8!$ different ways.

So we have
$$
8! \binom{9}{5}=\frac{8!\, 9!}{5! \,4!} = 5,080,320
$$
possibilities.